# for drag and drop in selenium

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

I am using selenium python to automate website which is developed through angular js. I am using actions chains for performing drag and drop but it is not working.

```
actionchains=ActionChains(self.driver)
actionchains.drag_and_drop(source_ele,dest_ele).perform()
```

I saved elements in source_ele and dest_ele variables.

please help me out to solve issue

Comment: any error is there?

Comment: Please provide details like Selenium version, AngularJS version and library used by Angular for this drag and drop feature (if available).

Comment: no i am not getting any issue.the source element is blinking

Comment: using selenium 3.3.1 version